# Fundamental lemma of calculus of variations with second derivative

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations

Intense debate at work place around the solution for this:

Let $M \in C[a,b]$ be a continuous function on the closed interval $[a,b]$ that satisfies $$\int_{a}^{b}M(x)\eta^{\prime\prime}dx = 0,$$  for all $\eta \in C^{2}\left[a,b\right]$ satisfying 
$\eta(a) = \eta(b) = \eta^{\prime}(a) = \eta^{\prime}(b) = 0$.
Prove that $M(x) = c_{0}+c_{1}x$ for suitable $c_{0}$ $c_{1}$.  What can you say about $c_{0}$, $c_{1}$?

I tried to use integration by parts, and use the fundamental lemma of the calculus of variations, and the lemma of Du Bois and Reynolds to prove it, but that requires $M$ to be $C^1([a, b])$.

Comment: At most work places, intense debates occur about more mundane topics, such as football, or politics. :-)

Comment: Nice question! Can you please provide further detail on your attempts so see if we can fix them?

Comment: we are a bunch of math geeks :p and we have those discussions too :)

Comment: Don't really see why this was put on hold. Seems like a reasonable question. I am voting to reopen

Comment: Now that the question has been answered, you should **accept** one of the answers (unless you are not satisfied with either of them). This is done by clicking on the tick sign which appears beneath the upvote/downvote arrows.

Answer (score 7):

This solution is more elementary than the one of Brian Moehring because it does not use mollificators. It also has the advantage of explicitly giving $c_0$ and $c_1$, as requested in the question.

Let me make a minor notation change and assume that $m\in C([0, 1])$ is the function with the property that 
$$
\int_0^1 m(t)\eta''(t)\, dt = 0, \qquad \forall \eta\in C^2, $$
where 
$$
\tag{*}\eta(0)=\eta(1)=\eta'(0)=\eta'(1)=0.$$ 
Define 
$$\tag{1}
M(x):=\int_0^x (m(t)-c_0-c_1t)(x-t)\, dt, $$ 
where $c_0, c_1$ are chosen in such a way that $M$ satisfies the boundary conditions (*). (See Remark, below, for more information on (1)). This amounts to solving a system of 2 linear equations in 2 unknowns, which is not singular, and thus admits one and only one such solution regardless of $m$. (The solution is given in the Appendix, below).

Now notice that the assumption on $m$ implies that, for every polynomial $P$ of degree 1, and for every smooth $\eta$ satisfying (*), we have that 
$$\tag{2} 0=\int_0^1(m(t)-P(t))\eta''(t)\, dt.$$ Indeed, integration by parts shows that $\int_0^1 P(t)\eta''(t)\, dt=0$. Using (2), we compute 
$$
0=\int_0^1 (m(t)-c_0-c_1 t)M''(t)\, dt = \int_0^1 (m(t)-c_0-c_1t)^2\, dt, $$ 
which finally implies 
$$
m(t)=c_0+c_1 t.$$

**Remark**. How did I come up with the formula for $M$? That is actually a special case of a general formula; the function 
$$
M(x)=\int_0^x \frac{(x-t)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} m(t)\, dt $$ 
satisfies $M(0)=M'(0)=\ldots=M^{(n-1)}(0)=0$ and 
$$
M^{(n)}(x)=m(x), $$ 
and is therefore known as "a $n$-th antiderivative of $m$".

**Appendix**. The values of $c_0, c_1$ are: 
$$
c_0=2\int_0^1 m(t)\, dt -\frac12\left( m(1)-m(0)\right), \quad c_1=m(1)-m(0).$$

Comment: +1: Very nice. ${}$

Comment: I'm a little confused how you're finding any information about $c_0$ and $c_1.$  Do we not have

$$\int_a^b (c_0+c_1x)\eta''(x)\,dx = c_0(\eta'(b) - \eta'(a)) + c_1(b\eta'(b) - \eta(b) - a\eta'(a) + \eta(a))$$
for all $\eta \in C^2[a,b]?$

Comment: @BrianMoehring: That must vanish. Indeed, $c_0+c_1 x$ has a vanishing second derivative, and because of the boundary conditions on $\eta$ you can integrate by parts without boundary terms. So, $\int_0^1 (c_0+c_1 t)\eta''\, dt =0$.

Comment: Right, so if that's true for all $c_0, c_1,$ how can we say anything about their values?  (That's the reason why I ignored the question of "what can we say about $c_0,c_1?$" because my answer is "nothing")

Comment: @copper.hat: Thank you so much. I am very glad you liked it, because I am a big fan of your posts on this site.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I agree that, given some $m(t),$ we can extract values for $c_0,c_1.$  My point in this context is simply that the choice of $m(t)$ is not unique, so given any $c_0, c_1,$ we can find $m(t),$ and vice versa.

Comment: @BrianMoehring: That's true. There is a 1:1 correspondence between functions $m$ satisfying that integral condition (i.e. $\int_0^1 m(t)\eta''(t)\, dt=0$ for all $\eta$ satisfying the boundary conditions), and pairs $(c_0, c_1)\in \mathbb R^2$. The map $m\mapsto (c_0, c_1)$ is written in the Appendix to this answer. The inverse map is $(c_0, c_1)\mapsto c_0+c_1 t$.

Answer (score 3):

Define $M_\epsilon(x) = (M \ast \phi_\epsilon)(x)$ where $\phi_\epsilon$ is a standard mollifier supported on $[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$.  Then for all $\eta \in C^\infty$ supported on $[a+\epsilon, b-\epsilon],$

$$\begin{align*}
\int_{a+\epsilon}^{b-\epsilon} M_\epsilon''(x)\eta(x)\,dx 
&= \int_{a+\epsilon}^{b-\epsilon} M_\epsilon(x)\eta''(x)\,dx \\
&= \int_{a+\epsilon}^{b-\epsilon}\int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon M(x-t)\phi_\epsilon(t)\eta''(x)\,dt\,dx \\
&= \int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon \phi_\epsilon(t)\int_{a+\epsilon-t}^{b-\epsilon-t} M(x)\eta''(x+t)\,dx\,dt \\
&= \int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon \phi_\epsilon(t)\int_a^b M(x)\eta''(x+t)\,dx\,dt \\
&= 0
\end{align*}$$

In particular, this shows that $M_\epsilon(x) = c_{0,\epsilon} + c_{1,\epsilon}x$ for $x\in [a+\epsilon, b-\epsilon].$

Since $M_\epsilon\to M$ pointwise on $(a,b)$ as $\epsilon \to 0^+,$ $M(x) = c_0 + c_1x$ for $a< x < b.$

Comment: I only have a small objection: it is not true that $M_\epsilon\to M$ uniformly on $[a, b]$. Take for example $M=1$ on $[a, b]$, then $M_\epsilon(a)=M_\epsilon(b)=1/2$ for all $\epsilon$. But that is irrelevant here, as pointwise convergence suffices for what you want.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Right, I think I was applying "converges uniformly on compact subsets of $(a,b)$" without including that context.  I'll change that.