# Deriving the Euler-Lagrange equation using partial integration

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

From our homework sheet (Germany):

> Consider the following variational problem $$ S [u] = \int_{0}^{1} \left( \frac{1}{2}u^{''}(x)^2-\lambda u^{'}(x) \right) {\rm d} x \to \min \quad \text{with} \quad u \in C^2(0;1) \cap C[0;1], 
> u(0) = u(1) = 0 $$ Derive the Euler-Lagrange equation using partial integration.

---

So I set $\phi(t) = S[u + tv]$ with $v \in C_{0}^{\infty}(0;1)$

Considering $u$ is a solution of the variation problem:
$$\phi'(t) = \int_{0}^{1}(u''(x)+tv''(x))v''(x)-\lambda v'(x)dx = 0$$ for $t = 0$.  So $$0 = \phi'(0) = \int_{0}^{1} u''(x) v''(x) - \lambda v'(x)dx$$

Integrating $ -v'(x)  \lambda$ gives you $$\int_{0}^{1}u''(x)v''(x)dx = 0$$

But how do I continue from here? If $u \in C^4(0;1)$ one could get

$$\int_{0}^{1}u^{(4)}(x)v(x)dx = 0$$

and thus $u^{(4)}(x) = 0$. Does anybody have an idea how to continue from here?

Comment: Euler-Lagrange equation must be seen as PDEs in the weak sens (or distributional). Note that your functionnal is ill-defined because both integrals may actually blow up, this strongly suggests to introduce Sobolev spaces or at least to accept a distributional framework.

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, we can find the minimum configuration for $u$ without knowing the EL equations as follows: The total derivative term in $S[u]$ always vanishes due to the boundary conditions (BCs), so we may write $S[u]$ with a non-negative integrand. The minimum of $S[u]$ is then clearly when the integrand is zero, i.e. $u^{\prime\prime}\equiv 0$. Together with the BCs, this leads to $u\equiv 0$.

Comment: Could you please expand on "The total derivative term in $S[u]$ always vanishes"? I don't really follow, this would mean that $S$ is constant.

Comment: I think the remark is that $-\lambda \int_0^1 u'(x) \mathrm{d} x = 0$ due to the boundary conditions on $u$, so $S[u] = \frac 12 \int_0^1 (u''(x))^2 \mathrm{d} x$.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: THIS IS WRONG**.

The Euler--Lagrange equation in this case is $u''=0$ **(this is actually not true, see comments)**. Indeed, as you correctly derived in the question, we must have
$$
\int_{0}^{1}u''(x)v''(x)dx = 0, $$
and $v\in C^\infty_0$ is arbitrary, so $v''$ is a general element of $C^\infty_0$. We conclude $u''=0$.

The only solutions to this Euler--Lagrange equation are affine linear functions $u(t)=at+b$, but we also need to impose boundary conditions $u(0)=u(1)=0$, which means that the only critical point is $u=0$ and we find the same result as [in the other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4680766/8157).

Comment: Let $h \in C^0$. From the equality $\int_0^1 h(x) v''(x) \mathrm{d} x = 0$ for every $v \in C^\infty_0$, I think that you can only draw the conclusion that $h$ is an affine function. Applied to $u$, this would mean that $u$ is a cubic polynomial. You can then rule out the quadratic and cubic terms by using the remark that the choice was not restricted to functions $v$ with compact support, but only vanishing at the endpoints.

Comment: Uh--oh, you're right and I am wrong. It is true that $h(x)=ax+b$ solves $\int_0^1 h v''\, dx=0$. Editing, thanks a lot.

Comment: Coud you explain how to derive that $h \in C^0$ is a affine function from $\int_{0}^{1}h(x)v''(x)dx = 0$ ?

Comment: @Jahi02: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3336209/8157

Comment: Very helpful that you wrote this 4 years ago! @Jahio2, in your setting, you actually have less requirements on $v$: you only need $v(0) = v(1) = 0$ (not that $v'(0) = v'(1) = 0$). So in a first step you can obtain that $u''$ is affine, then use $v$s with non-vanishing derivatives at the endpoints to conclude that $u'' = 0$, and eventually $u = 0$.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro math.stackexchange.com/a/3336209/8157 So here you showed that $\int_{0}^{1}h(x)v''(x)dx = 0$ for all $v \in C^2$ implies $h(x) = ax+b$. Is there a way to modify the proof to show the same thing for $v \in C^{\infty}_0$ ?

Comment: @Jahi02: that's not entirely true, I have some boundary assumptions on $v$ in my other post, where it is called $\eta$. The same proof will work with $v\in C^\infty_0$.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro yes true, but could you explain to me how you can do it with $v \in C^{\infty}_{0}$ because in your post you use $M(x)$ which is only in $C^2$ (if i see it corretly) and thus $\int_{0}^{1}h(x)M''(x) = 0$ to finish the proof. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Oh, I see. You are right, technically there is a further step here. At some point in the other proof I take $v=M$. Now $M$ is $C^2$ but it is not $C^2_0$. However, suppose that $\int h v''\, dx=0$ for all $v\in C^\infty_c$. Argue by density that this implies $\int h w''\, dx=0$ for all $w\in C^2$ such that $w(0)=w(1)=w'(0)=w'(1)$.